Slow Ubuntu 22.04 installation on x99 Xeon Mobo
I am assembling and setup a home lab PC. I am installing Ubuntu 22.04 OS.
Along installation steps, I did not choose any additional packages, simply selected skipped.
However, I'm always stuck right on 'Update and other software', on selected 'Minimal Installation' & 'Continue'.
Here are the specs of my PC:

Xeon 2640 v4
x99 Huananzhi Mobo
SSD 240GB, HDD 320GB

I have waited for 30min, and the cursor remained spinning.
I am wondering if it is common duration for Xeon server take to install Linux OS, e.g. Ubuntu, RHEL etc?

Having googled again, found that it was caused by one of my HDD, the old one being faulty. Once disconnected all other, with just primary SSD to install to, it works!
